# How to escape the % (percent) sign in C's printf

Tags: c, printf, format-string

How do you escape the % sign when using `printf` in C?

```
printf("hello\%"); /* not like this */
```

Comment: `"hello\%"` doesn't work because it produces the string `hello%` plus NUL just like `"hello%"`  does.

Comment: `"hello\%"` doesn't work because... for me... it does not compile. I used Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. The compilation fails with the message: `'%': unrecognized character escape sequence.`

Comment: @DjibrilNDIAYE It appears [clang and gcc had their reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142682/what-is-the-backslash-percent-escape-in-c) to go against the standard and allow `\%`.

Answer (score 518, accepted):

You can escape it by posting a double '%' like this: `%%`

Using your example:

```
printf("hello%%");
```

Escaping the '%' sign is only for *printf*. If you do:

```
char a[5];
strcpy(a, "%%");
printf("This is a's value: %s\n", a);
```

It will print: `This is a's value: %%`

Comment: "printf("hello%%");" is right. But it's not a escape I think. use printf("hello\045");

Comment: @Pablo Santa Cruz: this method to "escape" `%` is specific to `printf`, correct?

Comment: for formatted functions (afaik they ends all with an `f`) in general, indeed!

Comment: This is a special case of the very common rule in escaping systems that to get a literal escape symbol you use <escape symbol><escape symbol>.

Comment: Lai Jiangshan, this won't work. `\045` is compile-time escape that is part of the **language** and will turn into `%` when compiled. `printf` is a run-time function, so it deals with bytes of your string, not with C source code, and it has its own escape sequences that are parts of the **function**. In short, `printf` is a "language inside a language", and `printf("This is a's value: %s\n", a);` gives the same result as `printf("This is a's value: \045\0163\012", a);`.

Comment: `char a[5];` is too much, `char a[3];` would be enough. On little-endian systems, you can even use `*((long *)a) = '%%';` instead of `strcpy`, and on big-endian systems, `*((long *)a) = '%%\0\0';`.

Comment: Also, you can do this: `printf("hello%c", '%');`. However, `%%` is better because it doesn't use another argument.

Comment: Works also for `__android_log_print`

Comment: Some embedded builds of `libc` do not seem to include support for escaping the percent sign.

Comment: @Triang3l, or just use `const char *a="%%"`. A other way is `uint64_t s=0x0025256F6C6C6568ULL;` `printf((const char *)&s);`(will print `hello%`). But better do not use this method.

Answer (score 44):

As others have said, %% will escape the %.

Note, however, that you should never do this:

```
char c[100];
char *c2;
...
printf(c); /* OR */
printf(c2);
```

Whenever you have to print a string, always, always, always print it using

```
printf("%s", c)
```

to prevent an embedded % from causing problems (memory violations, [segmentation faults](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=Wikipedia%20segmentation%20faults), etc.).

Comment: The warning is generally appropriate however there may be situations in which you want to do "this" - as long as you know that the string you provide will be interpreted as a format string.

Comment: I came up with an alternate solution once - copy the buffer to another buffer and then go through it doubling up the % signs. I eventually came across this idea and replaced a 20-30 line function with one line. Don't worry, I did beat myself severely about the head, as I deserved.

Comment: True, but don't forget that 99% of the time when you get a format string, you get the arguments as a va_list, so you need to use vprintf. Thus, I'm technically correct ;)

Comment: It's so much easier to do puts( c ).  If

Comment: puts appends a newline. That's often unwanted behavior.

Comment: @Mikeage: If unwanted, do `fputs(string, stdout);` or `printf("%s", string);`

Comment: But <CString>.Format(L"%s", <char>) would absolutely cause my program crash. I'm still using <CString>.Format(L"%c", <char>) though it would crash sometimes.

Answer (score 36):

If there are no formats in the string, you can use [`puts`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fputs.html) (or [`fputs`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fputs.html)):

```
puts("hello%");
```

if there is a format in the string:

```
printf("%.2f%%", 53.2);
```

As noted in the comments, `puts` appends a `\n` to the output and `fputs` does not.

Comment: Worth mentioning fputs() also, as it directly reciprocates to fprintf().

Comment: puts also appends a newline [even if you already have one]. If you want that, great. Otherwise...

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: thanks for reminding me about `puts`. I never thought of `puts` for printing strings and jumped straight to `printf`. Not anymore.

Answer (score 12):

With itself...

```
printf("hello%%"); /* like this */
```

Answer (score 8):

Use a [double `%%`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/):

```
printf("hello%%");
```

Answer (score 7):

Nitpick:
You don't really escape the `%` in the string that specifies the format for the `printf()` (and `scanf()`) family of functions.

The `%`, in the `printf()` (and `scanf()`) family of functions, starts a conversion specification. One of the rules for conversion specification states that a `%` as a conversion specifier (immediately following the `%` that started the conversion specification) causes a `'%'` character to be written with no argument converted.

The string **really** has 2 `'%'` characters inside (as opposed to escaping characters: `"a\bc"` is a string with 3 non null characters; `"a%%b"` is a string with 4 non null characters).

Comment: techinically, it is still "escaping"; characters that are special need a way to "escape" their special meaning and be back to their "character nature"

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
printf("hello%%");
//-----------^^ inside printf, use two percent signs together
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use %%:

```
printf("100%%");
```

The result is:

> 100%

Answer (score 5):

You are using the incorrect format specifier. You should use `%%` for printing `%`. Your code should be:

```
printf("hello%%");
```

Read more [all format specifiers used in C](http://codeforwin.org/2015/05/list-of-all-format-specifiers-in-c-programming.html).

Answer (score 4):

The backslash in C is used to escape characters in strings. Strings would not recognize `%` as a special character, and therefore no escape would be necessary. `printf` is another matter: use `%%` to print one `%`.

Answer (score 3):

Yup, use `printf("hello%%");` and it's done.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `%` twice, that is `"%%"`

Example:

```
printf("You gave me 12.3 %% of profit");
```

Answer (score 2):

The double '%' works also in ".Format(…).
Example (with iDrawApertureMask == 87, fCornerRadMask == 0.05):
`csCurrentLine.Format("\%ADD%2d%C,%6.4f*\%",iDrawApertureMask,fCornerRadMask) ;`
gives the desired and expected value of (string contents in) csCurrentLine;
    "%ADD87C, 0.0500*%"