# Displaying percentage using NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

How do we display percentage character in objective-c?

I am using this:

```
[NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%.2f %", percentageQs]
```

But for some reason, it doesn't recognize the %. thought i could escape it using this \ but i was so wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape the % sign in C's printf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860159/how-to-escape-the-sign-in-cs-printf)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There was a similar question tagged `C` asked earlier today: [How to escape the sign in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860159/how-to-escape-the-sign-in-c) . Answer here is the same... use a double %%.

Answer (score 4):

% is used as an escape character, e.g. %@, %i, etc.

So to use the % sign then you use two, i.e. %%

Answer (score 0):

The code for percent sign in NSString format is %%. This is also true for NSLog() and printf() formats.