# Trouble displaying % in NSRunAlertPanel

Tags: nsstring, nsrunalertpanel

I am developing an Desktop application where I want to show a message in alert panel using NSRunAlertPanel.
I am doing the following things:

```
NSString *title = @"% Test";
NSString *message = @"% Test Message";
NSRunAlertPanel(title, message, @"Ok" ,@"Cancel" ,nil);
```

The alert panel show the title properly. i.e % Test
But, the message is est Message; I want to display % Test Message.

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry users! This has been posted already. Please refer the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860609/displaying-percentage-using-nsstring It works fine.

Comment: FYI : I've just edited my question to explain why it works in the title with a single % but in the message it needs %%.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
NSString *title = @"% Test";
NSString *message = @"%% Test Message";
NSRunAlertPanel(title, message, @"Ok" ,@"Cancel" ,nil);
```

---

Why?

`NSRunAlertPanel` uses `NSBeginAlertSheet`. Looking at the [documentation for NSBeginAlertSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000695-BBCJCCJH) you can see that there are more parameters after msg (specified by the `...`).

This tells us that title is just a string literally displayed but the message can have format parameters the same way that `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` does.

The way that a string specifies that there is going to be a parameter is by using a % character i.e. %i means '*put an integer here*', %@ means '*put an object's description here*'. You've just put a % by itself, which gets things very confused!

The double %% means this percent isn't me telling you that I want you to put anything special in there, I really just want the % please.