# Printing '%' with printf in C/C++

Tags: c, printf

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [How to escape the % (percent) sign in C's printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860159/how-to-escape-the-sign-in-cs-printf)

How can I print '%' in C?

E.g.:

```
printf("A: %.2f%", pc);
```

...fails, the compiler complains there is an invalid conversion. Of course an easy way is;

```
printf("A: %.2f%c", pc, '%');
```

But it's rather inelegant...

I looked on the web, but I didn't find any escape sequence for %. I thought % would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @KennyTM: definitely a duplicate

Comment: @iulian: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate/44529

Answer (score 8):

```
printf("A: %.2f%%", pc);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just double the '%' in the format string and it will print '%'.

Answer (score 1):

For future *printf* reference, type:

```
man 3 printf
```

on any Linux command prompt. It can do a *lot* of crazy stuff that most people just aren't aware of.

Answer (score 0):

%% will output % using printf.
[Check the example at the end of page here](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/printf.html)