# I want to print float value and % sign after value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

Example : 2.3666%
And I am Using.
But Not Working..

```
float n = 2.3666;
NSLog(@"%f%",n);
```

Comment: Just an FYI, when asking questions like this you should state what you were expecting and then what you were actually getting, either a value or the compiler warning/error itself.

Comment: -1 In what way "not working"?

Comment: While in general I agree with that sentiment, in this case it's so clear what's wrong that a detailed explanation is not really necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing '%' with printf in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156078/printing-with-printf-in-c-c)

Comment: Why would change the title and the question until it is nothing like the original!?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to [escape percent signs using `%%`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

```
float n = 2.3666;
NSLog(@"%f%%",n);
```

Answer (score 8):

Escape the `%`:

```
NSLog(@"%f%%",n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use %% to scape de % character in NString NSLog

Comment: You can't tell me you did not see 2 duplicate answers before you answered :)