# How can I print the '%' symbol?

Tags: c++, c, mfc, dialog, printf

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [How to escape the % (percent) sign in C's printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860159/how-to-escape-the-sign-in-cs-printf)

I want to print the *%* symbol like this: "8%2F16"

How can I print this string?

Comment: `std::cout << "8%2F16";`

Comment: did you read the manual before posting here, search on the web for `printf` or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to print using `printf`, you'll need to use `%%`: escape the `%` with another `%`:

```
printf("8%%2F16");
```

`%` is an escape character with a special meaning in the `printf` format string, and so itself needs to be escaped if you're trying to print it.

Answer (score 3):

Besides using `%%`, you can also use `%c`:

```
printf("8%c2F16\n", '%');
```

The `%c` trick is a good fallback if you can't remember how to escape a character properly in your string. (Although, off the top of my head, the only tricky ones are `"` and `%`.)

Comment: What is that code? A Unicode codepoint? Can you add some kind of reference?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I think I understand what you are asking now. The reference is the question that was asked.

Answer (score 2):

With the suitable escape sequence, like so: `printf("%%");`

(Or of course just as `puts("%");`, but I suppose you're talking about formatted output.)