# printf: unknown conversion type character ')' in format -Wformat

Tags: c, random, printf

I have written a C program it is giving the following compilation error.

```
rand_distribution.c:24:7: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘)’ in format [-Wformat]
```

at this line

```
 printf("%d: %d (%.2lf %) \n", i+1, frequencies[i],100.0 * frequencies[i] / TOTAL_COUNT);

My objective to get an output like this.
1: 333109 (16.66%)
2: 333113 (16.66%)
3: 333181 (16.66%)
4: 333562 (16.68%)
5: 333601 (16.68%)
6: 333434 (16.67%)
```

That is to say '%' before the ')' should be printed as it is without being interpreted.How do I achieve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // for rand(), srand()
#include <time.h>    // for time()

const int TOTAL_COUNT = 2000000;  // Close to INT_MAX
const int NUM_FACES = 6;
int frequencies[6] = {0}; // frequencies of 0 to 5, init to zero

int main()
{
   srand(time(0)); /* seed random number generator with current time*/

   /* Throw the die and count the frequencies*/
   int i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < TOTAL_COUNT; ++i)
   {
      ++frequencies[rand() % 6];
   }

   /*Print statisics*/
   for (i = 0; i < NUM_FACES; i++)
   {
      printf("%d: %d (%.2lf %) \n", i+1, frequencies[i],100.0 * frequencies[i] / TOTAL_COUNT);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to escape the `%` sign `%%`

Since `%)` does not match any variable type it fails. Escape it by adding a `%` before it.

Your new line should be,

```
printf("%d: %d (%.2lf %%) \n", i+1, frequencies[i],100.0 * frequencies[i] / TOTAL_COUNT);
```

Comment: Nope. The `%` is the one character that is escape differently.

Comment: Looks like this answer was edited after the downvotes and comment. If not, I don't understand the downvotes; the answer is redundant but correct.

Comment: @Dogbert What? Am I wrong?

Comment: @KeithThompson You are correct. This answer was corrected, but was initially incorrect (initial: `\%`, after edit: `%%`).

Comment: @KeithThompson I see what happened and yes, this first answer is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

To print a `%` with `printf` use `%%` conversion specification.

Replace

```
printf("%d: %d (%.2lf %) \n"
```

with

```
printf("%d: %d (%.2lf %%) \n"
```

To understand why `\%` does not work, see c-faq question:

*"Q: How can I print a '%' character in a printf format string? I tried \%, but it didn't work."*

http://c-faq.com/stdio/printfpercent.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want print `%` .You shuold write `%%`

:

```
printf("%d: %d (%.2lf %%) \n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `%%` to escape the character.

eg: `printf("Percent%%")` yields "Percent%".

So, in your case, your format string should look like `printf("%d: %d (%.2lf%%) \n",...)`

References:

---

1. [How to escape the % sign in C's printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860159/how-to-escape-the-sign-in-cs-printf)