# Difference between \% and %%

Tags: c, printf

After reading over some K&R C I saw that printf can "recognize %% for itself" I tested this and it printed out "%", I then tried "\%" which also printed "%".

So, is there any difference?

Edit for code request:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("%%\n");
  printf("\%\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
%                                                                               
%
```

Compiled with GCC using -o

GCC version: gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.8.1 20130909 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 202388]

Comment: you are right, but this works only with printf (using double % sign), so use it carefully

Comment: [Answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860159/how-to-escape-the-sign-in-cs-printf)

Comment: Run the `strings` command on the resulting program. The output will show you that the "\%" has been translated to "%" by the compiler when it constructed the string literal from your program source.

Comment: Which gcc version, which host?

Comment: @ouah; On my compiler I got only `%` with some warnings.

Comment: @ouah Edited question with GCC version

Comment: Could you replace the last `printf` line with `printf("1\%2\n");` and show the output? Could you also show the compiler output when compiled with `-Wall`?

Comment: %
1%2
...is the altered output. With -wall I get the following error: printf.c:6:3: warning: unknown conversion type character 0xa in format [-Wformat=]
   printf("1\%2\n");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%%` is not a C escape sequence, but a printf formatter acting like an escape for its own special character.

`\%` is illegal because it has the syntax of a C escape sequence, but no defined meaning. Escape sequences besides the few listed as standard are compiler-specific. In all likelihood the compiler ignored the backslash, and `printf` did not see any backslash at runtime. If it had, it would have printed the backslash in the output, because backslash is not special to `printf`.

Comment: I see, strange how the compiler just ignored it and carried on, instead of giving an error.

Comment: @CSStudent Best to use `-Wall` to enable more warnings.

Comment: I don't believe this specific case is covered by any `-W` option, it *is* covered by `-pedantic`, so if you really want it to be an error `-pedantic-errors` is your friend `;-)`

Answer (score 4):

Both are not the same. The second one will print `%`, but in case of the first one, you will get compiler warning:

> [Warning] unknown escape sequence: '%' [enabled by default] 
> The warning is self explanatory that there is no [escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) like `\%` in C.

### 6.4.4.4 Character constants;

says

> The double-quote `"` and question-mark `?` are representable either by themselves or by the escape sequences `\"` and `\?`, respectively, but the single-quote `'` and the backslash `\` shall be represented, respectively, by the escape sequences `\'` and `\\`.

It is clear that `%` can't be represented as `\%`. There isn't any `\%` in C.

Comment: Using GCC to compile, I don't get the warning you showed, the program actually compiles and runs. ( I didn't downvote btw c: )

Comment: BTW: "\%" is not illegal; unknown escaped characters are replaced by them selves. (eg "\"" )

Comment: @wildplasser I think they are invalid. See c99, 6.4.5p1 Syntax of string literals: a `\%` is not allowed in a string literal.

Comment: I stand corrected. IIRC it was valid in K&R. It must have been dropped in c89 or c99, then. (probably together with the introduction of the "longest match" rule for "\xabcdef" hex-escapes)

Comment: @wildplasser; I quoted from c11.

Comment: I looked it up in c99, so it must have been either c89 or c99 that changed it. My bet is on c99.

Comment: @wildplasser; Might be. Can't say anything.

Comment: This warning arises in the preprocessor (integrated in `gcc`). Unknown \-escapes are not an error in K&R (2e, A.2.5.2), "behaviour undefined" (though strings and chars are a little vague). This generates a warning from ANSI C onwards, whether you see the warning depends on `-pedantic`. You can observe the behaviour of `gcc` by using  `-traditional` (if it works for you) or `-ansi` (or `-std=c89` or later) to compile.

Comment: @mr.spuratic; Yes. By using `-ansi` flag, no warning is there.

Answer (score 0):

When `"%%"` is passed to printf it will print `%` to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29), but `"\%"` in not an valid escape sequence in C. Hence the program will compile, but it will not print anything and will generate a warning:

> warning: spurious trailing ‘%’ in format [-Wformat=]  printf("%");

The list of escape sequences in C can be found in *[Escape sequences in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)*.

This won't print `%` for the second *printf*.

```
    int main()
    {
        printf("%%\n");
        printf("\%");
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

Output:
`%`