# Why does printf("%%") print only one percent (%) symbol?

Tags: c, printf, stdio

When I run this following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main(){
    clrscr();
    printf("%%");
    getch();
}
```

I get % as an output?

What might be the reason behind this logic?

Comment: Because that's what it does. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1860164/242520

Comment: One escapes the other, simple :)

Comment: A few quick ways to print both of them: `printf("\%\%");`, `printf("%c%c",'%','%');`, `printf("%s","%%");`.

Comment: @barakmanos Are you sure that `\%` will work?

Comment: don't vote down for stupidity, the question is clear (very clear). Everyone starts stupid even you.

Comment: @richard: Not really, I just took it "out of the sleeve"...

Comment: I agree with @richard, don't down vote for stupidity. Down vote for no research effort.

Comment: @barakmanos the `%` system used by `printf` and family does not interact with the `\ ` system used by the language, so to escape a `%` you have to use a `%` i.e. `%%` and for two `%`s you can do `%%%%`. However it is better to only put formatting information in the formatting string e.g. `printf("%s","%%");` `printf("%s","hello %%");

Comment: @richard: Gotcha, thanks for the info. It's actually quite obvious that `'\%'` is **not** a special character, now that I think about it. BTW, you're missing a ` at the end of your comment above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is what `printf` does: it is print formatted (*f* for formatted). It uses `%` as the formatting character. It is the only reserved character and needs to be escaped to represent it self, i.e. `%%`. See the manual for more information on formatting: *[printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)*.

P.S.: Never use a string that is not a part of the program as the first argument. To print a string message that was input by a user, do `printf(%s, message);`. Otherwise you will have a security hole in your code.

Answer (score 2):

`%` comes into format specifiers.

#### Example

When we write `printf("%d", 20);`, it will print 20 rather than `%d`. because the compiler treats `%` as a format specifier. In the mind of the compiler, the meaning of % is somewhat special.

So if you want that "%" should be the output, then you must write `printf("%%")`. Here the first % sign will suppress the meaning of the `%` format specifier and will print `%` as an output.

Comment: I like your way of explanation, +1 @KailashKarki

Comment: Yes, but it is not the compiler that interprets the `%`. It is the `printf` procedure that does it. (```\``` in strings is interpreted by the compiler.)

Answer (score 1):

From the standard ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (E)

7.19.6.1

Each conversion specification is introduced by the character %.

The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:

% - A % character is written. No argument is converted. The complete
 conversion specification shall be %%.

Answer (score 1):

For C *printf*, `%` is a special character which typically indicates a parameter to substitute at that position: `printf("Hello, %s\n", "World!");` results in "Hello, World!". There are lots of different things you can put after the % depending on the data you want to output. So that leaves the problem of "What if I want to print a percent symbol"?

The solution: Use `%%`.

The same is true of the special escape character `\`. "\n" means to print a new line.  If you want to actually print the forward slash, you have to put it twice `\\`

See [Printf format string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx).

Comment: \ is part of C and C++, % is part of printf, though they work in a similar way.