# What will be Output in C?

Tags: c, printf, output

I ran the following code segment in C:

```
    printf("%%%\n");
```

I got the output "%" (without quotes). Can anyone explain what exactly happened?
Why we got only one % sign in result?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860159/how-to-escape-the-sign-in-cs-printf

Comment: Read [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) & wikipage on [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: actually, I got two `%%` sign

Comment: @rakib: I ran the code on Codeblocks13.12 using GNU GCC Compiler, & It gave only one % sign.
Which compiler are you using?

Comment: My gcc version is gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140624 (Red Hat 4.8.3-1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%%` will print `%`. `%\n` is not a valid [conversion specifier](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html).

You should always enable warnings. See the following:

```
 warning: unknown conversion type character 0xa in format [-Wformat=]
     printf("%\n");
                 ^
```

As noted in the comments, this is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because according to the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), it is undefined behavior if:

> — An invalid conversion specification is found in the format for one of the formatted input/ouptut functions [...]

Comment: why I got two `%%` as output?

Comment: @rakib Because %\n is not a valid format specifier. Because You should always enable warnings.

Comment: I ran the code on Codeblocks13.12 using GNU GCC Compiler, & It gave only one % sign with no warnings..
I even ran the
        printf("%\n");
but it also did not give any warnings..
I think warnings are enabled in my computer (coz I got some warnings in different questions).. Can you explain why is this happening?

Comment: @PascalCuoq ya, but that does explain why it shows `%%` output.

Comment: @Prakhar I picked the wrong standard quote. See edit.