# How to print the "%" character with printf

Tags: c++, c

The output of

```
printf("%%%%%%%%");
```

is

```
%%%%
```

I used `%` eight times. Why does the output only have four `%`s?

Comment: The % should be escaped.. %% represents one %

Comment: Albeit simple, the question doesn't deserve downvotes. It's concise, to the subject and clear. Also it's not trivial to find on google if you don't know the terms to search for.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: `man printf`? (and search for `%%` on the page).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath not everyone (including me) has `man` built-in the command line.

Comment: Not sure about the downvotes to question but sometimes SO amazes me with Votes on simple answers going as high as `9-10`. While, well thought and answers which need painful effort to write get max `2-3` votes.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: You asked for a google search term. I gave one. And searching *only* for `printf` works just as well (look, what a lovely chart..) Here's another one: `print % with printf` or `printf print %`

Comment: FWIW the first Google hit for `man printf` is [this page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf). Note that even with this web page in hand and knowing what to look for, it's still tough (but not impossible) to find it.

Comment: each language has it's own limitation and the escape characters are one of them. But each language also provides an other way round to handle it, Same is with C++. You have to write twice to print it once.

Comment: @Bector: not all specialised languages are so smart as to handle escaping escapes properly. Most are, but you still need to include it explicitly and some forgot.

Comment: Did you ever search for printf function format before asking this?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because `%` is a format specifier escape sequence (as in `%d` would print an `int`).

To get the program to print the actual symbol, you write `%%`. The same goes for `\` (although fundamentally different, you still need to to print one).

Comment: \ is a bit different.

Comment: @T.C. you need \\ to print a single \.

Comment: \ is built into the language, and `'\\'` is one character. `%` is specific to the formatted IO functions  - `"%%"` is two characters.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Yes, you need \\ to print a \, but the reason is fundamentally different. I think that remark without further explanation *could* be misleading.

Comment: what is the reason behind it?

Comment: @Angew I realize my formulation could have been misleading, edited.

Comment: @iharob Actually, the string is the same in both cases. It's just that \ is interpreted by the compiler at compile time, while % is interpreted by `printf` at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

The `"%"` is a special character, and it's used to specify format specifiers. To print a literal `"%"`, you need a sequence of two `"%%"`.

The `"%"` is used in the format string to specify a placeholder that will be replaced by a corresponding argument passed to the functions that format their output, like `printf()`/`fprintf()`/`sprintf()`.

So how can you print a literal `"%"`?

- Escaping it with another `"%"`.

If you for example wish to print an integral percentage value, you need to specify as the `"%d"` the format specifier and a literal `"%"`, so you would do it this way:

```
printf("%d%%\n", value):
```

Read [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) to learn more about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
"%%"
```

in printf is an escaped '%' sign. See this Stack Overflow answer: *[How to escape the % (percent) sign in C's printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860159/how-to-escape-the-sign-in-cs-printf)*