# Encoding URL characters

Tags: c, printf, output

I have very weird problem. I'm doing performance testing in LoadRunner and noticed that in some addresses I have weirdly coded characters.

I wrote a test app, this is the code:

```
char bla[256]="test %3A test %2B"; 
printf(bla);
```

The output has no sense. It looks like this:

> test 0X0.000000P+0 test B

What is going on here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860159/how-to-escape-the-sign-in-cs-printf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the problem here is caused by the presence of the `%`-ed elements like `%3A` and `%2B` in the array, and you're passing that to `printf()` as the only argument, without a format specifier string in place.

When you pass a string directly to `printf()` (as the first argument to `printf()`), it interprets those as format specifiers, and expect argument for that. But using

- invalid format specifier `%2B` and
- supplying less arguments  (in this case, should be *ideally* two)

are both [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can try changing you print statement to

```
 printf("%s\n", bla);
```

to make the `printf()` understand that those `%`s does not carry any special meaning, they are simply to be printed.

Comment: Thanks for help! I haven't been programming in C for few years, now it looks REALLY different after using almost exclusively C# and JS :P