# Strange format specifier in c with percentage character

Tags: c, printf, output, percentage, format-specifiers

I have a question related to a "printf" instruction in a c example:

```
printf("Percentage character: %%",10);
```

The output is correct: Percentage character: %

Why is that format-specifier (%%)?  What is with that 10 over there? Why the compiler says that are too many arguments for `printf`?

I tried to display the percentage character in another way:

```
printf("Percentage character: %c",putch(37));
```

However,the output is not really good: %Percentage charcater: %

Why it appears that percentage character before the sentence?

Comment: Did you carefully read documentation of [printf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)? Did you enable all warnings & debug info in your compiler (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860159/how-to-escape-the-sign-in-cs-printf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%%` conversion specification is used in `printf` to print a single `%` (no argument is converted).

For example:

```
 printf("10%%\n");
```

prints

```
 10%
```

Now in your example:

```
printf("Percentage character: %%",10);
```

is OK, but the `printf` second argument is just ignored. It's equivalent to:

```
printf("Percentage character: %%");
```

Regarding your last example:

```
printf("Percentage character: %c",putch(37));
```

both `printf` and `putch` write characters to the standard output, so first `putch` is evaluated and writes a character and then `printf` will write a serie of characters to the standard output. Use:

```
     printf("Percentage character: %c", 37);
```

if you don't want the first `%` or, better:

```
     printf("Percentage character: %c", '%');
```

if you want to be independent of the character set (37 is % in ASCII, but can have another value on other character sets).

Comment: Thank you!Could you tell me why the second output contains one extra percent before the sentence?

Comment: @RevnicRobert-Nick, that extra `%` is probably because of the evaluation of `putch(37)`.

Comment: @RevnicRobert-Nick the correct call is `printf("Percentage character: %c", 37);` (in ASCII), `putch` also writes a character to `stdout`.

Comment: Ok.I got it.I tried this instead: printf("Character: ");putch(37); It works fine.

Comment: @RevnicRobert-Nick I added an edit to cover this last case

Answer (score 2):

**Why is that format-specifier (%%)**

Think of a situation where you would want to print `%` through `printf()`. If you just give a `%` it would be taken as a part of some format specifier. So to print a `%` you need to do `%%`

---

**And what is with that 10 over there?And why the compiler says that are too many arguments for printf?**

`10` is just another parameter for `printf()`. As there is no format specifier to match that parameter, so you are getting the **`too many arguments for printf`** message

---

In this

```
printf("Percentage character: %c",putch(37));
```

`putch()` comes from standard library `conio.h` and  it is not supported on Linux,  As what [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) says, it is not defined by C standard.