# What is the backslash-percent escape in C?

Tags: c, gcc

This compiles without warning in clang and gcc:

```
const char *foo = "\%";
```

The resulting string is the same as `"%"`.

What is this escape for? Where can I find a complete list of escapes?

I thought maybe it was for escaping digraphs, but other digraph characters produce warnings (e.g. `"\:"`).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That's weird - I don't think this is a legal escape sequence. What compiler are you using?

Comment: The variable is not used - the source code above is complete. I guess the question can be phrased as, why does "\:" warn about unknown escape sequences, but "\%" does not?

Comment: You can escape just about anything.

Comment: @lurker Which context? You escape % in printf with %%, not \%.

Comment: @lurker I'm afraid not. printf("\%d", 5) outputs 5, not %d.

Comment: Yep, you're right. My test case was overly trivial.

Comment: @lurker It's libc dependent but it behaves the same as printf("%\n");

Comment: @ridiculous_fish processing of `'\'` is handled by the compiler, not the library

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question: it's to support SCCS, which is a 40-year old revision control system, that predates even RCS. Ha!

Digging into the compilers, clang supports this [because it thinks gcc does](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/LiteralSupport_8cpp_source.html#l00191):

```
case '(': case '{': case '[': case '%':
// GCC accepts these as extensions.  We warn about them as such though.
```

Lies! The warnings show up, but only with the `-pedantic` flag (in both compilers).

Oh, and gcc? It [supports the first three for emacs](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/athena/astaff/source/src-8.1/third/gcc/c-lex.c), which I guess is easily confused:

```
/* `\(', etc, are used at beginning of line to avoid confusing Emacs.  */
case '(':
case '{':
case '[':
```

but the last one:

```
  /* `\%' is used to prevent SCCS from getting confused.  */
case '%':
  if (pedantic)
      pedwarn ("non-ANSI escape sequence `\\%c'", c);
  return c;
```

SCCS support! It's glorious!

Answer (score 1):

According to the C standard, any escape sequence not mentioned by the Standard is a syntax error.

This means that the compiler must produce a diagnostic, but the compiler could define an extension (e.g. ignore the `\`) and continue compiling the rest of the program.

The standard escape sequences are: `\' \" \? \\ \a \b \f \n \r \t \v`, and also the octal, hex and universal character constants introduces by `\`(digit), `\x` and `\u` respectively.