# How to use sprintf to output the symbol % in a string?

Tags: c

I want to convert a percentage to a string via sprintf.
A workable way is like this:

```
sprintf(str, "%d", num);
strcat(str, "%");
```

But is there a way to only use sprintf to make it done?

Comment: `sprintf(str, "%d%%", num);`?

Comment: Always consult the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf): "A '%' is written. No argument is converted. The complete conversion specification is '%%'"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape the % sign in C's printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860159/how-to-escape-the-sign-in-cs-printf)

Answer (score 0):

*(Compiling an answer from comments, just to get this out of the list of unanswered questions.)*

Printing a `%` via `sprintf()` is done via `"%%"`, i.e. in your case thus:

```
sprintf(str, "%d%%", num);
```

Here is a quote from the helpful documentation:

> A '%' is written. No argument is converted. The complete conversion specification is '%%'