# Passing string containing "%" to http.ResponseWriter causes variable missing

Tags: string, http, go

w is of type http.ResponseWriter

This is fine:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, statusPercentage + " " + mostUpToDateStatusDownloaded + "/"+ mostUpToDateStatusOverallData)
```

output: 100 488 MB/488 MB

This causes a problem:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, statusPercentage + "% " + mostUpToDateStatusDownloaded + "/"+ mostUpToDateStatusOverallData)
```

output: 100%! (MISSING)MB/488 MB

Comment: Problem solved! It turned out that I have to escape the percentage sign by using double %. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860159/how-to-escape-the-percent-sign-in-cs-printf for further information.

Comment: You might have heard of Println.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`%` is a special placeholder symbol. If you want to put it into a string as a symbol itself - duplicate it. Like:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "Growth %v %%", "50")
```

Output:

```
Growth 50%
```

Comment: Your code makes use of wrong quotation marks. More specifically: `invalid identifier character U+201C '“'` and `invalid identifier character U+201D '”'`

Comment: Sorry, I sent from mobile phone - and looks like autocorrection decided to change symbols.

Answer (score 4):

It is usually not a good practice to use arbitrary application strings as the format specifier to fmt.Fprintf and friends.  The application should either using a fixed format string or convert the string to bytes and write the bytes directly to the response.

Here's how to do it with a format string:

```
// note that '%' is quoted as %%
fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s%% %s/%s", statusPercentage, mostUpToDateStatusDownloaded, mostUpToDateStatusOverallData)
```

Here's how to skip the formatting and write directly to the response:

```
io.WriteString(w, statusPercentage + "% " + mostUpToDateStatusDownloaded + "/"+ mostUpToDateStatusOverallData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `fmt.Fprintf` if you're not doing any string formatting? Just use [`fmt.Fprint`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Fprint) instead.