# How to show '%' symbol on C language output like the photo that i show?

Tags: c

[image]

How to show '%' symbol on C language output like the photo that i show ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape the % (percent) sign in C's printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860159/how-to-escape-the-percent-sign-in-cs-printf)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using printf(). In that case, use double % signs eg: `printf("100%%");`.