# conditional operator usage using printf in C

Tags: c

I need to consider the user input character is white space or not.
The program works well when I type in a blank space, `*` is printed out successfully.
But when I type a character that is not white space, I can't get `%`.
Instead the character that I entered is just printed out.

Is there a problem with my conditional operator code?

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    char character;
    printf("Press any single key\n");
    character = getchar();
    
    (isspace(character) > 0) ? printf("*") : printf("%");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%")` should be `printf("%%")`. A percent character on its own needs to be "escaped", because a complete format instruction such as `"%d"` is expected.

Comment: Fwiw printf(isspace(character)?”*”:”%%”); would work also.

Comment: `printf("%c", isspace(character) ? '*' : '%' )`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape the % (percent) sign in C's printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860159/how-to-escape-the-percent-sign-in-cs-printf)

Answer (score 2):

`%` is a special character in a `printf` format string. To output a `%` characters, you can:

- either use `printf("%%");`
- or use `putchar('%');`

Also note these problems:

- `character` should be defined with type `int` to reliably store all return values of the function `getchar()`, including the special negative value `EOF`.
- `isspace()` is defined for values of type `unsigned char` and the special value `EOF` returned by `getchar()`, do not pass a `char` value. Instead, define `character` as an `int` and pass that.
- `isspace()` does not necessarily return a positive value for whitespace characters, you should just test if the return value is non zero, which in C can be written:

  ```
    if (isspace(character)) {
        ...
  ```

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;

    printf("Press any single key\n");
    c = getchar();
    
    if (isspace(c)) {
        putchar('*');
    } else {
        putchar('%');
    }
    return 0;
}
```